# bash script to access a file in a remote host three layers deep

Tags: bash, shell

So in the terminal I access the remote host through ssh -p then once I'm in i have to `cd /directory1/directory2/`. Then I want to find the latest directory which I do using `ls -td -- */ | head -n 1` then using this I want to cd into that and `tail -n 1 file1`

All these commands work in the terminal but I want to automate it to where I can just type `./tailer.sh` and have that be output.

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The shell script `tailer.sh` can look something like this

```
#!/bin/bash
ssh -p <PORT> <HOST_NAME> '( cd /directory1/directory2/ && LATEST_DIR=$(ls -td -- */ | head -n 1) && cd ${LATEST_DIR} &&  tail -n 1 file1 )'
```

Then give execute permissions to `tailer.sh` using `chmod u+x tailer.sh`

Run the script using `./tailer.sh`

Comment: I think could be just `'tail -n1 "$(ls -td -- /directory1/directory2/*/ | head -n1)"/file1'`